# Reading XML to a Dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, readxml

I need to read an XML file to a dictionary.

I read few guides and I only got confused from weird words that I don't understand (such as nodes, XML validation etc.).
So, could you please walk me through?

I have an XML file which is written in this format:

```
<database>
    <def number="1" name="one"/>
    <def number="2" name="two"/>
</database>
```

As mentioned, I want to store it in a dictionary. How would I go about that?

Comment: Questions and answers such as this one are what makes this site so awesome. +1 for both.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var data = XElement.Parse(xml)
    .Elements("def")
    .ToDictionary(
        el => (int)el.Attribute("number"),
        el => (string)el.Attribute("name")
    );
```

This:

- parses the xml into an `XElement` (starting at `<database>`)
- iterates over the `<def ...>` elements
- forms a dictionary, using `@number` as the key (interpreting as an `int`), and `@name` as the value (as a string)
- assigns this dictionary to `data`, which is implicitly typed as `Dictionary<int,string>`

Answer (score 9):

Your question is basic, but not inappropriate. Don't worry. I'll explain what you should do.

first you have to load this XML file (if it's on the disk). Otherwise you don't need this step

```
XDocument database = XDocument.Load(pathToYourXmlFile);
```

up to here, you got:

```
<database>
    <def number="1" name="one"/>
    <def number="2" name="two"/>
</database>
```

Then you have to get a list of all **def** elements:

```
List<XElement> defs = database.Elements("def");
```

up to here, you got:

```
<def number="1" name="one"/>
<def number="2" name="two"/>
```

Now, you should get each item of the list (each def in defs):

```
foreach(XElement def in defs)
{
    // Here you have each def <def number="x" name="y" />
    int number = def.Attribute("number").value;
    string name = def.Attribute("name").value;
}
```

the code to extract information from each def is:

```
int number = def.Attribute("number").value;
string name = def.Attribute("name").value;
```

Now that you have your number and name, just add it to your dictionary.

```
dictionary.Add(number, name);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Should that be `database.Elements("def").ToList()` ?