# XPathNavigator performance with large secondary datasource

Tags: c#, xpath, xpathnavigator

I have a secondary DataSource with about 23k entries. The User inputs an ID and gets only 1 Dataset back.
If I use:

`XPathNavigator test = nav.SelectSingleNode("/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW[d:Title = '" + ID + "']", NamespaceManager);`

it takes about 8 seconds to return the Node. Is there a better (faster) way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collect all the `SharePointListItem_RW` nodes in a `Dictionary` (**key** would be the title id and the **value** would be the node that contains the title as id) at the start of your app..

[Memory consumption would not be an issue here since it would hardly cross 1MB]

Then you can select the particular node by using `TryGetValue` method of `Dictionary`

The complexity would be `O(1)` which is fast

Comment: any hints how to put all the nodes into a dictionary? And that is fast?

Comment: ok but how to put all SharePointListItem_RW nodes in a Dictionary?

Comment: @DanielR check out [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578658/reading-xml-to-dictionary)

Comment: this explains usage of dictionaries. But how should I get all the 23000 nodes into a dictionary in a reasonable time? Or did you mean something completly different?

Comment: great but is this also available in VSTA (C# 2005)??

Comment: Yes, it is.  Dictionary<string, XPathNavigator> dict = new Dictionary<string, XPathNavigator>(); foreach(XmlNode n in nav.SelectSingleNode("/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW", NamespaceManager)){ dict.Add(n.SelectSingleNode(d:Title, NamespaceManager).Value, n); }

Comment: In reality, though, you should probably be filtering the data source when you query it.  I don't suppose you need all 23,000 of those records at once, do you?